# VRS JobTicket: Extension Tickets & +1 Capabilities

Tags: public-transport, germany, cologne, bonn

The [VRS Transit Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsverbund_Rhein-Sieg) (serving the area including Cologne and Bonn) offers a ["Job Ticket"](https://www.vrsinfo.de/tickets/tickets-fuer-job-und-ausbildung/jobticket.html) which is a monthly transit pass that is made available to employees working at certain companies.

A relatively unusual characteristic of this transit pass is that it has a +1 ability in that during evenings after 7pm (to 3 am the next day) and all day on weekends & official holidays, the pass holder can bring one adult (14+) and three children (6-13) and a bike with them free of charge.

An additional unusual characteristic of this transit pass is that there are a number of supplement/extension tickets which allow the pass holder to travel beyond the normal coverage area for a cost that is less than the fare available to a non-pass holder.  Specifically, there is:

- [VRS-AnschlussTicket](https://www.vrsinfo.de/tickets/tickets-fuer-job-und-ausbildung/jobticket.html) which for 3.70 € allows the pass holder to travel to the "extended VRS network which consists of several nearby towns in Rhineland-Palatinate.
- [EinfachWeiterTicket](https://www.vrsinfo.de/tickets/tickets-fuer-job-und-ausbildung/jobticket.html) which for 6.70 € allows the pass holder to travel to the AVV Network (e.g. Aachen area) or the VRR Network (e.g. Dusseldorf area).
- [Airport Schnellbuszuschlag](https://www.swb-busundbahn.de/service/flug-und-bahnreisende.html) which for 3.10 € allows the pass holder to travel on the express bus connecting central Bonn to the Cologne/Bonn airport.

How does the +1 capability apply to each of the above extension tickets?  If a pass holder and one non-pass holder adult wanted to travel to/on a transport that would normally require a supplement during a time when the Job Ticket's +1 capabilities are in effect, which of the following is the bare minimum required to meet the fare requirements?

A) Is one Job Ticket plus one extension ticket sufficient to cover the two adults?

B) Is one Job Ticket plus two extension tickets sufficient to cover the two adults?

C) Is one Job Ticket plus one extension ticket plus one normal non-pass holder fare required?

Comment: [Note on whether this question is on topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4796/are-questions-asked-by-locals-about-local-transit-on-topic-for-travel-se)

Comment: I've seen a lot of unexplained random downvotes, but in this case, I have no earthly idea why someone would possibly downvote this question.

Comment: The question is legitimate, IMHO, but the answers can be found with a very quick online search.

Answer (score 5):

A very quick search for "VRS Anschluss Ticket" reveals the official page (by VRS), where it is stated that for VRS-AnschlussTicket and EinfachWeiterTicket that additional persons travelling on the pass holder's pass have to get their own ticket.

For example for the VRS-AnschlussTicket:

> Achtung: AnschlussTickets gelten nur in Verbindung mit VRS-Zeittickets und jeweils nur für eine Person. Bei Mitnahme von weiteren Personen – z. B. im Rahmen der Abo-Mitnahmeregelungen – ist zusätzlich ein AnschlussTicket pro Fahrt und weiterer Person zu lösen. Die Geltungsdauer des AnschlussTickets beträgt 360 Minuten. Für Fahrräder benötigen Sie ein separates FahrradTicket.

Should be pretty clear.

Comment: That answers one of the three cases asked about. What about the other two?

Comment: Search for the other ticket types; I stated "for example"… But you can be assured that there are no differences.